# Show that $ \lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}\max_{Q_{T-\varepsilon}}f=\max_{Q_T}f $

Tags: real-analysis

> For $T>0$ define the cylinder $Q_T\subset{\Bbb R}^3$ as
>   $$
> Q_T=\Omega\times[0,T]
> $$ 
>   where $\Omega=\{(x,y,0)\in{\Bbb R^3}\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. Let $f:Q_T\to {\Bbb R}$ be a continuous function. Show that
>   $$
> \lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}\max_{Q_{T-\varepsilon}}f=\max_{Q_T}f
> $$
>   where $Q_{T-\varepsilon}:=\Omega\times[0,T-\varepsilon]$.

---

I think uniform continuity of $f$ might be useful here. Let $y_\varepsilon\in Q_{T-\varepsilon}$ and $y\in Q_T$ be such that 
$$
f(y_\varepsilon)=\max_{Q_{T-\varepsilon}}f,  \quad f(y)=\max_{Q_T}f. 
$$

We have $Q_{T-\varepsilon}\subset Q_{T}$ though, I don't see if $|y-y_\varepsilon|$ would be necessarily small when $\varepsilon>0$ is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that $|y-y_\varepsilon|$ may not be small. But a little more work will give you the result. Let
$$
\phi(\varepsilon)=\max_{Q_{T_\varepsilon}}f.
$$
$\phi$ is a decreasing function of $\varepsilon$ and id bounded by $\max_{Q_{T}}f$. Then $\phi(\varepsilon)$ converges as $\varepsilon\to0$. It is not difficult to show that the limit must be $\max_{Q_{T}}f$.

Comment: Why is the limit must be $\max_{Q_T}f$?

Comment: It certainly is $\le \max_{Q_T}f$. Suppose it is $<$, use continuity and arrive to a contradiction.